# Displaying database values with radio button selection in Qt?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I want to show some database row values with radio button selection in Qt GUI. How this can be accomplished?. This could be done using foreach loop I guess. I have studied a bit about the following classes :

1) QMainWindow
2) QSqlTableModel
3) QTableWidget.

But which one satisfies my requirement? I am not able to implement it, please guide me. Thanks in advance.

I have implemented upto this in my source file-

**main.cpp**:

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QtSql>
#include <QTableWidget>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QRadioButton>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QGroupBox>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QTableWidget* table = new QTableWidget();
    table->setWindowTitle("Connect to Mysql Database Example");

        QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
        db.setHostName("localhost");
        db.setDatabaseName("guests");
        db.setUserName("sri");
        db.setPassword("******");
        if (!db.open())
        {
          QMessageBox::critical(0, QObject::tr("Database Error"),
          db.lastError().text());
        }

        QSqlQuery query("SELECT * FROM new_members");

        table->setColumnCount(query.record().count());
        table->setRowCount(query.size());

        int index=0;
        while (query.next())
        {

            table->setItem(index,0,new QTableWidgetItem(query.value(0).toString()));
            table->setItem(index,1,new QTableWidgetItem(query.value(1).toString()));

            index++;

        }

// This is sample radiobutton from QGroupBox class. Like this I need to implement the values from DB in with radio button selections for each value

        QMainWindow *window = new QMainWindow();
        window->setWindowTitle(QString::fromUtf8("QGroupBox"));
        window->resize(400, 400);
        QGroupBox *groupBox = new QGroupBox("Radio Buttons");
        QRadioButton *radio1 = new QRadioButton("Radio button 1");
        radio1->setChecked(true);
        QVBoxLayout *vbox = new QVBoxLayout;
        vbox->addWidget(radio1);
        groupBox->setLayout(vbox);
        window->setCentralWidget(groupBox);
        window->show();

        table->show();
                                         //MainWindow w; w.show();

        return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `QSqlTableModel` to drive a `QTableView`, you will need a custom `QStyledItemDelegate` to *draw* the `QRadioButton` ([yes I said draw, and not create](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstyleditemdelegate.html#details)), and create an editor widget (of course that really will be a `QRadioButton`).

This is quite a big job, so you will need to read the above class' docs to reimplement the bits you need.  Start with the [MVC documents](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/model-view-programming.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your Answer, as I am new to Qt, please kindly explain me step-by-step procedure (still simplified) to accomplish my task ... :)

Comment: If you're new to Qt, then you need to learn, and you're not going to learn anything from a step-by-step guide (not to mention what you are doing is not trivial).  Read the MVC docs, then create a program that can load an existing SQL db into a `QSqlTableModel`, by the time you have done that you will have specific issues which you can post as new questions on this site.